# Import-SPWeb can not find my .cmp folder

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, export, import

I have exported a document library from Farm A as follow:-

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://famrA/***" -ItemUrl "Our Library" -Path "c:\16.cmp"     -nofilecompression  -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity -Force -Verbose
```

Now this command has generated a folder named 16.cmp which contain many files.

Now I moved the folder to the C drive inside FarmB. then I wanted to import the document library inside the new farm using this command:-

```
Import-SPWeb http://farmB/**** –Path "c:\16.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity –Verbose
```

but I got this error:-

> Import-SPWeb : The file c:\16.cmp does not exist.

So can anyone advice on this, please? now the Export did not create a file named 16.cmp, But it created a folder named 16.cmp ...so not sure how to fix this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue occurs in case you are using `-NoFileCompression` parameter in the `Export-SPWeb` cmdlet.

In this case, the cmdlet will export the files with no compression in a **Folder** instead of one file `filename.cmp` as shown below

[image]

And if you tried to import it, you will get `The file c:\16.cmp does not exist` **because** it's not file, it's a folder called `16.cmp`

---

So to perform `Import-SPWeb` from `NoFileCompression` folder, you **must** also use the same `NoFileCompression` parameter in the `Import-SPWeb` cmdlet as shown below:

[image]

**P.S:** In your case, change Qassas folder to your folder name 16.cmp

**The final cmdlet based on your entries**

```
Import-SPWeb http://farmB/**** –Path "c:\16.cmp" -NoFileCompression -IncludeUserSecurity –Verbose
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... will try this and let u know if it work for me